# How to select from frames with the Watir Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby, exception, watir, frames, frameset

When trying to select a list element's option I attempted to do:

```
myvar=ie.select_list(:id, 'myid').option(:text, 'mytext').select
```

But for some reason while I'm using Watir in irb to access the website and attempting to manipulate any of the items I get this exception.

```
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: Unable to locate element...etc
```

I'm looking at page in the browser but using .html isn't showing the full page. It looks like the rest of the page is hidden and I'm not sure how to get into/around this.

```
irb(main):011:0> ie.html
=> "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>My Title</TITLE>\r\n
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript type=text/javascript src=\"../../script.js\"></SCRIPT>\r\n</HEAD><FRAMESET id=mainFrameSet name=mainFrameSet rows=100%,0%><FRAME id=frmMain src=\"DefaultT.cfm?ID=2197024\" name=frmMain><FRAME id=frmHidden src=\"Dummy.html\" name=frmHidden scrolling=no></FRAMESET></HTML>"
```

**EDIT:**
Looking at this in retrospect I have changed the title so it would more accurately address the issue I was having. It was difficult for a new waiter user to find information like on Watir and Frames. The original title was something like "Using Watir On An Encrypted Site". I have **severely** edited the question to get to the essence of what I was asking. I can't thank those enough who attempted to answer the ramblings of a new Ruby user with minimal knowledge of the Web and programming in general. Please see previous revisions if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the html you added, your webpage is using frames. Unlike other elements, you have to explicitly specify the frames you want to use.

You probably want the frame with id 'frmMain', so try:

```
myvar=ie.frame(:id, 'frmMain').select_list(:id, 'myid').option(:text, 'mytext').select
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the element is not on the page when you try to access it.

Try this (please notice `when_present`):

```
myvar=ie.select_list(:id, 'myid').when_present.option(:text, 'mytext').select
```

More information: http://watirwebdriver.com/waiting/

Comment: Unfortunately I'm working in IRB and so that seems unlikely. I did make an attempt (in IRB) but it times out after 60 seconds. Thanks for the waiting infromation. I'm sure it will come in handy soon, if I'm actually able to access the emelents.

Comment: You weren't working with the whole story since this answer is pre-edit. I belive you would have come up with the answer. Thanks again for your contribution and the amazing way you support us Watir users. I've seen you all over the place. I didn't want you to think it goes unnoticed or unappreciated.